# Is $\zeta^2(3)$ irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta, rationality-testing

It is known that Apéry's constant defined as
$$\zeta (3)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac {1}{n^3}= \frac{5}{2}\sum _{{n=1}}^{\infty }{\frac  {(-1)^{{n-1}}}{n^{3}{\binom{2n}{n}}}}=1.2020569\cdots$$
was proven to be irrational by Roger Apéry in 1979.

> But is $\zeta^2(3)= 1.44494079\cdots$ also irrational?

I have input this value into Wolfram Alpha, and the program cannot tell if the value is rational or not, so I assume the rationality of $\zeta^2(3)$ is unknown. However, I do not quite understand the difficulty of proving the rationality of $\zeta^2(3)$ since $\zeta (3)$ is already proven irrational. I know that $\pi^2$ and $e^2$ are irrational, but why is it hard to prove the rationality of $\zeta^2(3)$?

Comment: It is not known weather it's transcendental or not, so don't be surprised if you don't receive an answer.

Comment: Well, $\sqrt2$ is irrational...

Comment: In general, proving things are irrational is hard.  The question you should be asking instead is "why is it [relatively] easy to prove that $\pi^2$ and $e^2$ are irrational?".

Comment: $ a_n={\frac  {(-1)^{{n-1}}}{n^{3}{\binom{2n}{n}}}}$, can you sketch the proof that $\sum _{{n=1}}^{\infty }a_n$  is irrational ? Where does it fail for $(\sum _{{n=1}}^{\infty }a_n)^2=\sum _{{m=1}}^{\infty } (\sum_{k\le m}a_k a_{m-k})$ ?

Comment: Apery's approximations give a sequence of rational numbers $p_n/q_n$ such that $\left|\zeta(3)-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|\leq C/q_n^{1.08}$. If, for example, one had faster approximations, with $\leq C/q_n^{2+\delta}$, with $\delta>0$, then it would follow from Liouville's theorem that $\zeta(3)$ is not a quadratic irrational.